# codepen countdown clock glitch

Tags: javascript, countdown, clock

http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/MwNPVq/

I'm using a countdown clock from codepen because it's very easy to style in css. There's just one issue: the clock restarts every time the page is refreshed.

What modification do i need to make in the javascript to specify an exact end date?

```
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

Comment: The value of `endtime` passed to `initializeClock` is based on `new Date()`, which is the current time of whenever that javascript runs.

Comment: See that line that says `var deadline = ...`? Change that to whatever date you want. For example, March 22nd would be `new Date(2016, 2, 22)`. [Updated CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNWMQV)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply set the deadline to whatever you want, by changing this line:

```
var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

into

```
var deadline = new Date(2016, 3, 1 , 14, 00, 00);
```

This example will set the deadline to April 1st, 2016, at 2pm.

*Good point by [Mike C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/371184/mike-c): months are zero-based (January is 0, February is 1, etc.)*

#### Modified Codepen